# How to verify additional CarUxRestrictions?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-automotive

I have app which is distraction optimized, so it can run while driving whereas other apps can't even start, so in general **CarUxRestrictions** are in place. I also printed `carUxRestrictions.activeRestrictions` and it gives me `255`, so since those are flags it means that e.g. [UX_RESTRICTIONS_LIMIT_STRING_LENGTH](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/car/drivingstate/CarUxRestrictions#UX_RESTRICTIONS_LIMIT_STRING_LENGTH) should apply. Furthermore I've printed `carUxRestrictions.maxRestrictedStringLength` which gives me `120`, so my expectation was that I should **not** be able to display string longer than 120 in my activity. However, I can do that without any issue or even log warning with this ugly but functional Composable displaying 140 characters string:

```
Text("123456789a123456789b123456789c123456789d123456789e123456789f123456789g123456789h123456789i123456789j123456789k123456789l123456789m123456789n")
```

Do I misunderstand this restriction or maybe those restrictions are not working with composables yet?

Comment: The flag UX_RESTRICTIONS_LIMIT_STRING_LENGTH doesn't directly prevent displaying long strings.
It specifies the maximum allowed length for general-purpose strings that the system might restrict in driving mode.
This means the system might truncate or shorten strings exceeding this limit, but it doesn't guarantee complete enforcement in all situations.Instead of displaying the full 140 characters, consider truncating it to the maxRestrictedStringLength and displaying an ellipsis ("...") to indicate the remaining content.

Comment: @waseemakram thanks for answer but if there is a limit and system is not enforcing it then to me it looks the same as there would not be a limit. Is there some way to test this restriction and to see that string is truncated by system or activity blocked for not respecting the restriction? I've tried using Toast but it has it's own limit (in my case ~80 chars) irrelevant to CarUxRestrictions.